# Add number to a variable while in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, addition

I want to add the same number to a variable but it just comes out as 0 when I print. I want it so it keeps adding the number to the variable.

I tried this but it is not seeming to work

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a good question. This page also notes: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.